# Сделать owl slider carousel адаптивным под сетку bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, owl-carousel

В проекте используется сетка bootstrap и слайдер owl slider carousel.

В десктопном варианте выводится по два слайда. Как сделать чтобы при ширине 991px и меньше, выводилось по одному слайду?

Вот мой код:

```
owl.owlCarousel({
    navigation : true,
    dots: false,
    slideSpeed : 300,
    paginationSpeed : 400,
    items : 2,
    itemsDesktop : true,
    itemsDesktopSmall : true,
    itemsTablet: true,
    itemsMobile : true,
    navigationText : ["",""],
    responsiveClass:true,
    responsive:{
        991:{
            items: 1

        }
    }
});
```

**UPD**

При адаптировании слайда, в скрипте задается не подходящая ширина `item`. Как в `owl` изменить точки останова?

Comment: Попробуйте убрать `items : 2` из опций и добавить нормальные параметры для responsive https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/responsive.html

Comment: если убрать `items : 2` из опций, весь слайдер ломается

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## owlCarousel 1

Как достигается адаптивность на старой версии слайдера. У нас есть 5 точек, где мы можем прописать различное количество слайдов:

```
owl.owlCarousel({
    ...
    items : 2 // по-умолчанию 2
    itemsDesktop:false,
    itemsDesktopSmall:[991,1], // если размер экрана меньше или равно 991 количество слайдов - 1
    itemsTablet:false, 
    itemsMobile:false,  

});
```

> This allows you to preset the number of slides visible with a
>   particular browser width. The format is [x,y] whereby x=browser width
>   and y=number of slides displayed. For example [1199,4] means that
>   if(window<=1199){ show 4 slides per page}

## owlCarousel 2

На новой версии слайдера мы прописываем несколько объектов, названия которых соответствуют минимальной ширине. Объекты содержат переопределенные параметры слайдера, можно переопределить не только количество слайдов, но и, например,  включать навигацию и тп.

```
owl.owlCarousel({
    ...
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items: 1
        }
        991:{
            items: 2

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: так пробовала, не работает.

Comment: @MarinaVoronova где-то можно посмотреть? Ссылка на страницу?

Comment: к сожалению нет, проект лежит локально

Comment: @MarinaVoronova, как я понимаю, у вас старая, первая версия owl slider, _которая больше не поддерживается_. [Обновите слайдер](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/) и используйте предложенные правки

Comment: да, старая версия 1.3.2. а как можно обновить если я использую gulp? owl ставила с помощью bower

Comment: @MarinaVoronova Тогда нужно указать в вопросе, что нужно для старой версии. Хотя лучше обновите

Comment: спасибо! обновление помогло

Answer (score 1):

Как то так:

```
    var itm = 2;

    if(window.screen.width <= 991)
    {
     itm = 1;
    }

    owl.owlCarousel({
        navigation : true,
        dots: false,
        slideSpeed : 300,
        paginationSpeed : 400,
        items : itm,
        itemsDesktop : true,
        itemsDesktopSmall : true,
        itemsTablet: true,
        itemsMobile : true,
        navigationText : ["",""],
        responsiveClass:true,
        responsive:{
            991:{
                items: 1

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: спасибо за решение. вроде должно работать. но у `owl-item` в скрипте задается не подходящая ширина, из-за чего часть следующего слайда видна.

Comment: попрубуйте убрать `responsive:{
            991:{
                items: 1

            }`

Comment: если убрать, то сосвсем не адаптируется

Comment: спасибо! после обновления все работает корректно

Comment: you welcome :) )

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример из документации. Нажмите на кнопку "выполнить код" и увидите одну колонку. Нажмите на "Развернуть фрагмент" и увидите три колонки.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    responsiveClass:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1,
            nav:true
        },
        991:{
            items:3,
            nav:true
        },
    }
})
});
```

```css
.owl-carousel div{
   
    background: #4DC7A0;
  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>



<div class="owl-carousel">
  <div> Your Content 1 </div>
  <div> Your Content 2</div>
  <div> Your Content 3</div>
  <div> Your Content 3</div>
  <div> Your Content 4</div>
  <div> Your Content 5</div>
  <div> Your Content 6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: так пробовала, не работает